# How to prevent restart my node server after an error has occurred?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Connection.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "xxx.amazonaws.com",
  user: "admin",
  password: "xxx",
  database: "xxx",
  multipleStatements: true,
});

  var connect= ()=> { return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

    mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      else{
        resolve ("Success")
      }
    });

  })
}
module.exports = { mysqlConnection,connect};
```

Server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  
  var fetchDetail = `xxxx`
   
  connect()
    .then((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
      mysqlConnection.query(fetchDetail, (error, result, fields) => {

        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
         else {
          console.log("Successfull");
          res.send(result);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
     let e=new Error("Something went wrong")
     next(e)

    })
  }
);

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

If I hit ("/") when my internet is closed I get an error as a response because server is unable to connect with Aws MySQL instance. But after I restart my internet and hit ("/") I am still getting an error response until I restart my node server again.

Goal: I do not want to restart my server after any error.

Comment: Could your browser cache the response? You can easily check it from the dev-tools of your browser.

Comment: You're sharing one mysql connection between all requests, and when that connection breaks, your app ends up in a broken state.

Comment: @Challe I am sending the response and it's successfully shown in the browser. Can u tell me how to see the cache response?

Comment: @AKX but here I am using MySQL connection only once to get some data.

Comment: It depends on your browser. Open your browsers developer tools and choose the network tab, If you use firefox the "transferred" column will show you how much data the request has transferred or if it has been cached. On chrome its the same but it "size" column instead of "transferred".

Comment: Yes it has something in the size column the whole row is in Red

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to restart all server.
You need to look for `fatal` flag on `err` in your `.catch((err)=>{`
and try to reconnect to mysql then you catch fatal: error (like disconnect) by calling `mysql.createConnection({ ... params ... });` again

Comment: Will, it is not an infinite loop if the internet remains closed. It keeps on calling the connect until it not get established.